# Capture ... passed to function without mangling the !! operator

Tags: r, tidyverse, rlang

I need to forward `...` to a function argument, extract the symbols as code, and convert them to characters, all while preserving names. I usually use `match.call(expand.dots = FALSE)$...` for this, but it mangles the `!!` operator.

## Current behavior

```
f <- function(...){
  match.call(expand.dots = FALSE)$...
}

f(a = 1234, b = !!my_variable)

## $a
## [1] 1234
## 
## $b
## !(!my_variable)
```

## Desired behavior

```
f <- function(...){
  # whatever works
}

f(a = 1234, b = !!my_variable)

## $a
## [1] 1234
## 
## $b
## !!my_variable
```

**EDIT** Even better:

```
f <- function(...){
  # whatever works
}

my_variable <- "my value"
f(a = 1234, b = !!my_variable)

## $a
## [1] 1234
## 
## $b
## [1] "my_value"
```

Comment: What are the downstream consequences that this is affecting? The R language itself doesn't have a proper `!!` operator. The `rlang` package interprets that double function call to mean something special, but if you parse it with the default parser, you get the double negation.

Comment: following up on MrFlick, the hacky solution is to simply check the `quoted` value for the double ! and deal with that case individually

Comment: @MrFlick, I want to retain the option to evaluate `!!` later. I would also settle for evaluating `!!` right away as in the edit above. From @lionel's recent webinar (I assume he's the same Lionel), I recall that this is possible in `rlang`, but I do not remember how.

Comment: Never mind: I think `f <- function(...){rlang::exprs(...)}` works just fine. @MrFlick, if you post that answer, I will accept it. You nudged me in the right direction.

Comment: Actually, I’d like to see how you used that. I’ve not used that function myself. If you post your own answer, I’d gladly upvote.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The following code appears to work. The use case is [here](https://github.com/ropensci/drake/issues/200). Thanks to MrFlick for nudging me in the right direction.

```
f <- function(...){
  rlang::exprs(...)
}

my_variable <- "my value"
f(a = 1234, b = !!my_variable)

## $a
## [1] 1234
## 
## $b
## [1] "my_value"
```

**EDIT**: by the way, I am still looking for a way to parse `!!` without evaluating it. This would enhance user-side functionality related to https://github.com/ropensci/drake/issues/200.